# Pandas pd.isnull() function

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace not null values in my dataframe with 1  and null values with 0.

Here is my dataframe:

```
my_list= [['a','b','c'],['test1','test2',None],[None,'101','000']]

mydf= pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

mydf

    col1   col2  col3
0      a      b     c
1  test1  test2  None
2   None    101   000

mydf.where((pd.isnull(mydf)),0,inplace=True)

mydf

   col1 col2  col3
0     0    0     0
1     0    0  None
2  None    0     0
```

I am not sure why it is replacing not null values with zero. pd.notnull() does the opposite. Can anyone explain what I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do:

```
mydf = mydf.notnull() * 1
mydf
```

[image]

**For completeness**

```
mydf.isnull() * 1
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. But I wanted to know why pd.notnull does the opposite thing. Is it a bug. This is completely misleading!

Comment: @Rtut Could there be a confusion about pd.isnull and pd.notnull? pd.notnull returns True if the value is NOT null.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior for [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). According to the docs, `where` keeps values that are `True` and replaces values that are `False`, and `pd.isnull` will return `True` only for the `None` entries, which is why they were the only ones that were kept.

You either want to use the [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) function with `pd.isnull`:

```
mydf.mask(pd.isnull(mydf), 0, inplace=True)
```

Or you want to use `where` with `pd.notnull`:

```
mydf.where(pd.notnull(mydf), 0, inplace=True)
```

Regardless, @piRSquared's method is probably better than either of the above.

Comment: @Rtut, this answer answers your question: `But I wanted to know why pd.notnull does the opposite thing`